# Question about example of CAT($k$) space

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, geometric-group-theory, metric-geometry

Good time of day. I have the following question. It's written in wiki in examples of CAT($k$) spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT(k)_space) that the closed subspace $X$ of $\mathbb E^3$ (where $\mathbb E^3$ is a 3-dimensional Euclidean space) given by $X=\mathbb E^3 \setminus \{(x,y,z)|x>0, y>0, z>0\}$ equipped with the induced length metric is not a  CAT($k$) space for any $k$.

I want to understand why it's true.

If you don't mind can you please explain this question in more details?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at triangles with vertices on the border, like $(x,0,0)$, $(0,y,0)$ and $(0,0,z)$ for example

Comment: @Didier as I understand I need to use CAT($k$) inequality and use the following proposition: geodesic metric space $X$ is said to be CAT($k$) space if every geodesic triangle in $X$ with perimeter less then $2D_k$ satisfies the CAT($k$) inequality(Where $D_k$ is a diameter). Am I right or not? If you don't mind can you please explain this more detail? Thank you for your time